# Maximal ideal in $=\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-10}]$

Tags: ring-theory

I am working in the ring  $R=\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-10}]=\{a+b\sqrt{-10}\mid a,b\in\mathbb Z\}.$ I am trying to find a maximal ideal $I$ of $R$.

I thought about using the fact it is a PID and use one of the irreducible elements such as $(2)$ but I realised it is not a PID.

Comment: It's not a PID. $\langle 2,\sqrt{-10}\rangle$ is not principle.

Comment: The ideal $\langle 2\rangle$ is not prime, and thus not maximal, because $\sqrt{-10}\cdot \sqrt{-10}\in\langle 2\rangle$ but $\sqrt{-10}\not\in\langle 2\rangle.$

Comment: ‘ Principal’, not ‘principle’.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Find a prime $p\in\Bbb Z$ such that $\left(\frac{-10}{p}\right)=-1$, that is, a prime $p$ such that there is no solution to the equation $x^2\equiv_p -10$.

---

This is because:

> $$\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-10}]/(p)\cong\Bbb Z_p[x]/(x^2+10)$$ If $x^2+10$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Z_p[x]$, then the quotient is a field, which means that $(p)\subset\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-10}]$ is a maximal ideal.

Comment: @mathstudent101 No, since $x^2\equiv_7 -10\equiv_7 4$ has solutions $x\equiv_7 \pm 2$. The ideal $(7)$ is then not prime, since $14=(2-\sqrt{-10})(2+\sqrt{-10})\subset (7)$, but neither $2+\sqrt{-10},2-\sqrt{-10}$ are inside $(7)$. You are looking for a prime $p$ such that $$x^2\equiv_p -10$$ has **no** solution. The smallest such prime is $3$, since $$x^2\equiv_3-10\equiv_3 2$$ has no solution.